# Do we say "put" a rental bike shop?

Tags: american-english, british-english, collocations

I can't come up with anything better than to **set up** a (specialist) shop in an area.

Imagine a park up in the mountains where kids could do MTB (mountain biking?) a place that is accessible but lacking in facilities. How could we improve this park so anyone could go and do this activity? A student of mine wrote

> One idea might be **to put a rental bike shop** near the future park.

Now, it's understandable but are retail shops "put" in a place? I'm thinking "setting up a shop" is a better expression but it may not be the best. To **establish a shop** suggests a shop that needs to make a name for itself so it becomes a permanent feature in the area. **To make a shop** suggests building one from scratch,  ***to found a shop*** is the wrong collocation as that is often used for the creation of a large important business.

So, is there another way of saying "**put a shop**" there? It sounds like a game of Monopoly, players can *put* houses and hotels in Mayfair or Boardwalk but we don't *put* shops, I know there are better alternatives.

Comment: This native speaker of American English hears nothing at all wrong with your student’s *put a shop*. Although putting may not be an action that we typically think of shops as undergoing, in this context I find it unobjectionable.

Comment: I will flag answers in comments. This is a question that I think can be useful for learners and future visitors.

Comment: Shops can not only be "put" (or prevented from being put) somewhere. [*London County Council refused to **allow** shops and offices.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22refused+to+allow+shops%22)

Comment: The boy is using "put" perfectly naturally - from his point of view, it's "hypothetical planning", and he's adopting the role of a councilor who might decide where commercial premises will or won't be allowed / encouraged.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The young Italian speaking student is not in any imaginary committee or council, he's explaining why the park should have a "bikes for hire" shop. It's a good idea, but "put a shop" sounds a little off to me. I immediately said it was understandable but for level B2, maybe there are more idiomatic solutions.

Comment: bike rental shop, I'd use...but this question really surprises me as "put" seems fine to me. In architecture informal parlance, one would most definitely use "put". "When they built the mall, where did they put the bike shop?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I think you miss my point. I knew the "young Italian speaking student" was unlikely to have been a native Anglophone (or you're have said so). The *usage* is natural, even if the *specific* speaker isn't in a position to "use it naturally". And from his perspective (as a potential *customer*), he's more like a council planner than an actual shopkeeper. He just wants a shop there, and he could say *They should put a shop there* without even consciously thinking whether ***they*** refers to council planners, a nationwide bike shop chain, or a couple of guys making a business plan.

Comment: I like the "**they should put a shop there**".

Comment: I don't think put is a good verb to use in this context.  It's [pretty rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+up+a+shop%2C+open+a+shop%2C+put+a+shop&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @BillyKerr if you write an answer, including the Ngram, I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: @BillyKerr here's another ngram, I limited the time range, and selected "coffee shop”  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+up+a+coffee+shop%2Copen+a+coffee+shop%2Cput+a+coffee+shop&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think a google ngram search is really good enough for a definitive answer - it's just a rough guide to usage.  I think main issue with the "idea of putting" a shop somewhere is that it's a bit odd in this context, not ungrammatical.   There's nothing wrong with it per se, it's just that in democratic countries at least, shops are not opened by the decree of local planners.  You have to find someone willing to start a business first, and run it.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think an answer that says and demonstrates that the expression *put a shop* is uncommon is the beginning of a good answer. Who has said that "put a shop" is ungrammatical? Not me. Furthermore, I cannot in all conscience accept Lambie's answer, which also suggests "locate" because of its ambiguity. Does *locate* mean "to look for"  or to "position" sth (a shop)  somewhere? And I'm definitely not accepting an answer with a list of 11 verbs.

Comment: Perhaps in this context "incentivise the opening of a bike rental shop"

Comment: It's too wordy, but interesting that you, too, prefer "bike rental shop"" to "rental bike shop". Maybe I should ask about that too in a separate question :)?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you have already gone through a few options. Here are some other alternative that come to mind.

- Establish a shop
- Set up a shop
- Open a shop
- Start a shop
- Place a shop
- Launch a shop
- Create a shop
- Install a shop
- Position a shop
- Site a shop
- Station a shop

Which is *best* would depend on what you wish to convey. **Establish a shop**: This phrase implies stability and permanence. Is this going to be a permanent or long lasting shop? **Open a shop**: This is much more straightforward. It emphasizes the beginning of the business. **Set up a shop**: This would convey the idea of initiating the presence of a shop. It suggests the action of arranging and organizing the shop at the chosen location. **Launch a shop**: This works better in marketing material.

Comment: Which one is best though? I would automatically discard "install", "position" and "station". Please choose three or four and explain why they are preferable. Thanks.

Comment: It would depend on what you wish to convey.

**Establish a shop:** This phrase implies stability and permanence. Is this going to be a permanent or long lasting shop?

**Open a shop:** This is much more straightforward. It emphasizes the beginning of the business.

**Set up a shop:** This would convey the idea of initiating the presence of a shop. It suggests the action of arranging and organizing the shop at the chosen location.

**Launch a shop:** This works better in marketing material.

Comment: Fine, please edit the answer and include your thoughts. A long lists of words without any explanation is not helpful, unless you are a native speaker but even then.... You have also included two options which are in the question itself.

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but did you find this list of synonyms online? On a thesaurus, perhaps? In any case, I cannot accept this answer because I strongly disagree with a few of the suggested options. Also, two of the descriptions you supplied (establish, set up) were already in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Sample: One idea might be to **put** a rental bike shop near the future park.

**Nothing wrong with "put"** **a shop near some other thing.**

More formal:  **locate** -  One idea might be to **locate** a rental bike shop near the future park.

But that would be for more formal contexts.

> The Parish Plan at Yarpole “It has been very much a community-wide
> project. The management of the Parish Plan, by the Parish Council and
> others, started this process by achieving about 65% of community
> involvement in it in some way or the other through questionnaires,
> special interest groups and other aspects of the community and finally
> a huge exhibition was held in the church which included an enormous
> scale model of the parish. When proposals were being developed **to put
> the shop in the church**, this idea was used again and an exhibition of
> the proposals was put up in church as a way of getting people used to
> the idea of using the church for secular use”.

[social enterprise](https://plunkett.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/places_of_worship_and_social_enterprise_final_report.pdf) [bolding mine]

Comment: Which would you choose between "put a shop", "set up a shop" or "establish a shop" in any given area? Are all three acceptable and *nothing wrong*?

Comment: I would say put or locate or set up. Never "establish" under normal circumstances. To establish a business. "set up" make it sound like the shop is there, and you are setting up your wares there. For construction/building, I'd say put (informal) or locate (formal).